# how to solve tkinter module install Error

Tags: tkinter, python-module

PS C:\Users\Sankalp> pip install tkinter
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter

Comment: What makes you install tkinter? Just try casually saying `import tkinter` in your python shell and see if it throws any error. tkinter is usually preinstalled with python

Comment: You can't install tkinter with pip.

Answer (score 0):

The Tkinter module cannot be installed with Python PIP. Judging from the `C:\Users\%USERNAME%>` prompt that you have included in your question, I would assume that you are trying to install Tkinter on Windows. In that case, the official Python installer for Windows should have installed Tkinter along with Python. To check, you can run `import tkinter` or `import Tkinter`, depending if you are using Python 2 or Python 3, and if it doesn't throw an error, then you have Tkinter preinstalled.